# Timed Javascript Events

Tags: javascript, time

I want certain events in the code to trigger some sort of a timer, and for that timer to be used as a condition in another place (to cause events after a certain number of seconds for example).  Is there any way to create "timers" like this in Javascript?  (without libraries)

Comment: That's pretty much *exactly* what `setTimeout` is for.

Comment: How do I use setTimeout then?

Comment: Google: JavaScript setTimeout.

Comment: check out setTimeout() and setInterval().

Comment: When your event happens, say `setTimeout(function() { /* do action here */ }, some_number_of_milliseconds);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this

```
 setTimeout(function(){
     alert("Do something")
 },300);
```

where 300 is number of millisecounds to wait before doing something